# Como exibir os valores do Cursor usando Debugger no Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, debug

Eu estou muito acostumado a usar apenas o [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat?hl=pt-br), enquanto estou depurando um aplicativo. Mas percebo que o [Debbuger](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/?hl=pt-br) é uma ferramenta muito mais poderosa. Eu posso pausar o estado da aplicação e observar suas variáveis.

Eu consigo obter a posição do cursor e a contagem de linhas que o cursor tem. Mas não consigo encontrar o valor de cada coluna da database usando o debugger.

Não seria lógico e possível fazer isso usando o debbuger? 
Se não é possivel, por que?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquilo que consegue visualizar directamente pelo *debugger*, na aba ***Variables***, é o valor dos campos de um objecto(variáveis).

O objecto Cursor não tem nenhum campo com os valores das colunas da posição actual. Eles são obtidos através do uso de métodos.

O *debugger* tem um recurso chamado ***Evaluate Expression*** [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] que permite o calculo de expressões Java, incluindo a chamada a métodos.
Use-o para inspeccionar o valor de cada coluna, chamando esses métodos.

Comment: Você tem razão, o cursor não armazena em nenhum lugar os valores de das colunas. Apenas a posição, a contagem de colunas e outras coisas. Obrigado!